# How to calculate time difference between two timestamps(minutes) in angular reactive forms?

Tags: angular

How to calculate time difference between two timestamps(minutes) in angular reactive forms

Example: 1st input start time(11:50), 2nd put end time(12:50) and output should be 01:00 in the 3rd output field

I am using bootstrap date picker.

```
<input type="time"  class="form-control reset" (change)="sum()" id="start_time{{i}}" formControlName="start_time" [(ngModel)]="start_time">
<input type="time" class="form-control reset" (change)="sum()" id="end_time{{i}}" formControlName="end_time" [(ngModel)]="end_time">
<input type="text" class="form-control reset" id="task_time{{i}}" formControlName="task_time"  [(ngModel)]="total_time">
```

create.ts

```
 sum () {
    this.task_time = this.start_time - this.end_time;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: it's impossible for me know if your timestamps are number, string or dates, if you use a library to show the time edit the question adding more information

Comment: **not** use `[NgModel]` and `formControlName` in the same tag. One is for Template driven form and another for ReactiveForms. Choose how you want manange the form

Answer (score -1):

well, they are strings, so simple convert to minute, get the difference and  convert to hour

So make two functions

```
stringToMinutes(value: string):number {
    const parts = value.split(':');
    if (parts.length == 2 && !isNaN(+parts[0]) && !isNaN(+parts[1]))
      return +parts[0] * 60 + (+parts[1]);

    return 0;
  }
  minutesToString(value:number):string
  {
    const hours=Math.floor(value/60)
    return (hours>0 && hours<99?('00'+hours).slice(-2):''+hours)+":"+
            ('00'+(hours%60)).slice(-2)
  }
```

Noew, when change you can call to

```
calcule()
  {
    this.diference=this.minutesToString(this.stringToMinutes(this.end)-
                   this.stringToMinutes(this.start));
  }
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvtued?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: Sorry for the null explain (I'm in hurry now)

**update**

split create an array from a string, so, e.g. split("12:30") return ["12","30"]

To calculate minutes multiply by 60 the first element of the array and add the second element of the array, but first we need convert to number (this is the reason to add a `+` and be sure that they are number

the construction ('00'+variable).slice(-2) add a "0" if the variable is less 10

Math.floor return the integer part of a division

the module operator `%` return the rest of a division